# Load from Xml to Canvas and it disapears

Tags: java, xml, canvas

I making a Leveleditor I can save it to xml and load . When I load from xml and set the stats to the grid of the canvas it shows right after 2secounds it disapears and shows the old grid but why?
This is my Grid Class:

```
private int gridSizeX, gridSizeY;
private Color color;
public boolean isFinish = false;
private Tile[][] tile;
private int pushID;

public Grid(int gridSizeX, int gridSizeY) {
    this.gridSizeX = gridSizeX;
    this.gridSizeY = gridSizeY;

    tile = new Tile[gridSizeX][gridSizeY];

    for (int x = 0; x < gridSizeX; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < gridSizeY; y++) {
            tile[x][y] = new Tile(x * 32, y * 32);
            tile[x][y].setTileID(pushID);                      
            pushID++;

        }
    }
}


public void Update() {
    for (int x = 0; x < gridSizeX; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < gridSizeY; y++) {
            tile[x][y].Update();

        }
    }       
}


@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    for (int x = 0; x < gridSizeX; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < gridSizeY; y++) {
            tile[x][y].paintComponent(g);
            isFinish = true;

        }
    }       
    super.paintComponent(g);
}

public Tile getTileAt(int x, int y) {

    try {
        return tile[x][y];
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println("NULL");
    }

    return null;
}

public void setTileAt(int x, int y, Color color1) {
    tile[x][y].setColor(color1);

}

public void Load(String filePath) {
        SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
        File xmlFile = new File(filePath);

      try {

        Document document = (Document) builder.build(xmlFile);
        Element rootNode = document.getRootElement();

        List<Element> list = null;
        for (int x = 0; x < gridSizeX; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < gridSizeY; y++) {                   
                list = rootNode.getChildren();
            }
        }       
        Element node = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

           node = (Element) list.get(i);

           System.out.println(" XPos : " + node.getAttributeValue("XPos"));
           System.out.println(" YPos : " + node.getAttributeValue("YPos"));
           System.out.println(" Image : " + node.getAttributeValue("Image"));
           System.out.println(" ID : " + node.getAttributeValue("ID"));


        }

        for (int x = 0; x < gridSizeX; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < gridSizeY; y++) {   
                tile[x][y].setTileID(Integer.parseInt(list.get(tile[x][y].getTileID()).getAttributeValue("ID")));
                tile[x][y].setX(Integer.parseInt(list.get(tile[x][y].getTileID()).getAttributeValue("XPos"))); 
                tile[x][y].setY(Integer.parseInt(list.get(tile[x][y].getTileID()).getAttributeValue("YPos"))); 
                tile[x][y].setImagePath(list.get(tile[x][y].getTileID()).getAttributeValue("Image")); 
                System.out.println(tile[x][y].getTileID());




            }

        }       

      } catch (IOException io) {
        System.out.println(io.getMessage());
      } catch (JDOMException jdomex) {
        System.out.println(jdomex.getMessage());
      }


}

public void ClearGrid() {
    for (int x = 0; x < gridSizeX; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < gridSizeY; y++) {
        }
    }
}

public void Save() {

    try {


        Element company = new Element("Tiles");
        Document doc = new Document(company);


        for (int x = 0; x < gridSizeX; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < gridSizeY; y++) {
                Element daten = new Element("Daten");
                daten.setAttribute(new Attribute("ID", String.valueOf(tile[x][y].getTileID())));
                daten.setAttribute(new Attribute("XPos", String.valueOf(tile[x][y].getX())));
                daten.setAttribute(new Attribute("YPos", String.valueOf(tile[x][y].getY())));
                daten.setAttribute(new Attribute("Image", tile[x][y].getImagePath()));

                doc.getRootElement().addContent(daten);
            }
        }


        XMLOutputter output = new XMLOutputter();
        output.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
        output.output(doc, new FileWriter("Test.xml"));

        System.out.println("XML File was created successfully!");

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Can you please provide the relevant snippet of code showing what you have so far? Given this little information, there's no way to provide a helpful answer yet.

Comment: Hej i have Edit my Question.. i cant put all in :D or need my GUI class?